# Are different types of sensor data got by onSensorChanged of the same quantity?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I mean, for the code below, will _aBuffer.size(), _laBuffer.size(), .... all be the same?

I've tried the same code on different devices, one is 'yes', the other is 'no', but i don't know if there is some issues with the second device's hardware, because it has some strange behavior

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    int eType = event.sensor.getType();
    float[] values = event.values.clone();

    if (eType == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        _aBuffer.offer(values);
        System.out.println("onSensorChanged values: "+values[0]+","+values[1]+","+values[2]);
    } else if (eType == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
        _laBuffer.offer(values);
    } else if (eType == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
        _gBuffer.offer(values);
    } else if (eType == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        _mBuffer.offer(values);
    } else if (eType == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
        // do nothing
    } else if (eType == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        _gyroBuffer.offer(values);
    } else if (eType == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
        _rotBuffer.offer(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't tell us what these buffers are ...

Comment: @Lieuwe, just LinkedList<float[]>, i thought the .offer(values) method implicits that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of sample depend on the value you gave in

```
public boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate)
```

The size of the sample must be same theoretically.But in practise it not always true.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29)

says

> The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. **Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster.** The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST. or, the desired delay between events in microsecond.

Comment: i'm getting stuck with the sensors... 2 issues i cant resolve. On some devices the 4 rate levels have no effect on type_gyroscope and type_rotation_vector; on some phones type_gyroscope gets a muuuuuch hiiiiiigher sample rate, seems like 10 times faster than the other types of sensor, have you ever come across that thing?

Comment: Dont constant SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST..these constants have different valuses for different devices.Use hard coded values in microseconds

Comment: besides, the docs you quoted **Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster.** does not say whether different types of sensors got same sample rate or not, it just say the rate may vary, but maybe different sensors may vary simultaneously, isn't so?

Comment: when receiving gyroscope values, still neither hardcoded values nor constant SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST etc. works on my second phone ... how to check where the issue is? i'm not sure if that's mistake of my hardware

Comment: I read in forums regarding malfunction gyroscope frequeny ,which hardware your using ?

Comment: try checking gyro frequency with "gyroscope log" app